# How to run a loop in R to find a unique combination of numbers within a range of 7?

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataset which looks something like this:-

```
Key Days
A 1
A 2
A 3
A 8
A 9
A 36
A 37
B 14
B 15
B 44
B 45
```

I would like to split the individual keys based on the days in groups of 7. For e.g.:-

```
Key Days
A 1
A 2
A 3

Key Days
A 8
A 9

Key Days
A 36
A 37

Key Days
B 14
B 15

Key Days
B 44
B 45
```

I could use ifelse and specify buckets of 1-7, 7-14 etc until 63-70 (max possible value of days). However the issue lies with the days column. There are lots of cases wherein there is an overlap in days - Take days 14-15 as an example which would fall into 2 brackets if split using the ifelse logic (7-14 & 15-21).
The ideal method of splitting this would be to identify a day and add 7 to it and check how many rows of data are actually falling under that category. I think we need to use loops for this. I could do it in excel but i have 20000 rows of data for 2000 keys hence i'm using R. I would need a loop which checks each key value and for each key it further checks the value of days and buckets them in group of 7 by checking the first day value of each range.

Answer (score 4):

We create a grouping variable by applying `%/%` on the 'Day' column and then `split` the dataset into a `list` based on that 'grp'.

```
grp <- df$Day %/%7
split(df, factor(grp, levels = unique(grp)))
#$`0`
#  Key Days
#1   A    1
#2   A    2
#3   A    3

#$`1`
#  Key Days
#4   A    8
#5   A    9

#$`5`
#  Key Days
#6   A   36
#7   A   37

#$`2`
#  Key Days
#8   B   14
#9   B   15

#$`6`
#   Key Days
#10   B   44
#11   B   45
```

#### Update

If we need to split by 'Key' also

```
lst <- split(df, list(factor(grp, levels = unique(grp)), df$Key), drop=TRUE)
```

Comment: Works out well. I was trying out different combinations of days to look for exceptions. Found an issue:-

key <- as.character(c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'))
days <- as.integer(c(1,2,3,8,14,36,38,14,16,44,47))
df <- data.frame(key,days)

grp <- df$days %/%7
grp1 <- split(df, factor(grp, levels = unique(grp)))
grp1

In the output A & B are grouped together as:-
$`2`
key days
5   A   14
8   B   14
9   B   16

$`1`
key days
4   A    8

We need to split this. We can probably run a loop which will do this separately for each unique key. No clue how though.

Comment: Checked it. It does splits out the key. Thanks. But still fails if the gap is exactly 7.
$`1.A`
  key days
4   A    8

$`2.A`
  key days
5   A   14

Tried making it 8, then it works; however then it splits out the constituent of the B keys:-
  key days
8   B   14

$`2.B`
  key days
9   B   16

Comment: @HKaushik  Probably it is not clear then about the question.

Comment: @HKaushik  For the dataset in the comments, what is the expected?